# Estimate values of $g$-factor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, magnetic-moment

I'm not sure I understand how to compute the gyromagnetic ratios. 
Here's what figured out:

if we consider an orbiting charged point-like massive particle we can $\textit{classically}$ compute the dipole angular momentum:

$\mu=iS=\frac{q}{2m}L=\gamma L$

where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio (ratio between dipole angular momentum and angular momentum)

Now we consider a deuteron. Consider for instance an orbiting proton getting a $\textit{quantum}$ dipole angular momentum

$\hat{\mu}^p_{l}=g_p\frac{e}{2m_p}{\hat\ell}=g_p\mu_N\frac{\hat\ell}{\hbar}=\gamma_p\hat\ell$

$\hat{\mu}^p_{l_z}=\gamma_p\hat\ell_z$

here $\gamma_p$ is the gyromagnetic ratio and $g_p$ is the g-factor (which measure how much the value of $\hat\mu_p$ deviate from the one computed before).

then, we can define the intrinsic orbital dipole momentum as the eigenvalue of $\hat\mu_{\ell_z}$ on the state of maximum projection:

$\mu_{\ell}=<\ell,m_z=\ell|\hat\mu_{\ell_z}|\ell,m_z=\ell>=g_{\ell}\ell\mu_N$

analogously for the spin:

$\mu_{s}=<s,m_z=s|\hat\mu_{s_z}|\ell,m_z=s>=\frac{1}{2}g_s\mu_N$

now, it is said that "since orbiting proton could be considered a point-like particle then $g_p=1$". Does this mean: "we can ignore the intrinsic and quantum proprierties of the proton and consider it a point-like particle so that the system is the same of the classical one (apart from $\hbar$) and $g_p$ should be 1"? (this way the intrinsic orbital magnetic dipole is an $\ell$ multiple of the nuclear magneton, whatever it means (what does it means?))

On the other side, it is said that $g_s=2$ comes from the Dirac equation (at first order, ignoring qcd...). But could we expect it by noticing that if $g_s=2$ then the intrinsic spinorial momentum equals the nuclear magneton? What would that mean? Is there another reason to guess the (wrong, but ignore this) $g_s=2$ without solving Dirac equation?